# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build on dynamic widget creation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am facing an error **setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build** while changing the state of the widget by calling changeState() function on **onTap** of **InkWell** element. Can anyone help me to find where I am doing wrong. I've tried all the possible solutions available over the internet. Following is my code:

```
class AdressenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdressenWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AdressenWidget> createState() => _AdressenWidgetState();
}

class _AdressenWidgetState extends State<AdressenWidget> {
  String _heading = '';
  String _name = '';
  String _address = '';
  String _telefon = '';
  String _email = '';
  bool _isChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeEAProvider();
  }

  Future initializeEAProvider() async {
    await locator<EAProvider>().initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<EAProvider>(context, listen: true);
    provider.initialize();
    
    return Consumer<EAProvider>(
      builder: (context, v, child) => Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 10),
        decoration: auftragBox,
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: v.expandAdrWidget,
            child: SizedBox(
              child: mainBody(v.addressList, v.isDashboard),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget mainBody(List<Addressobject> addressList, bool isExpanded) {
    var adress = getData(addressList, list[0]);
    _heading = adress.heading;
    _name = adress.name;
    _address = adress.address;
    _telefon = adress.telefon;
    _email = adress.email;
    _isChecked = adress.isChecked;

    return Column(
      children: [
      IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 170,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              changeState(addressList, i); //here is the issue
                            },
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.location_pin,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ))],
    );
  }

  

  void changeState(List<Addressobject> addressList, int index) {
    var adress = getData(addressList, list[index]);
    setState(() {
      _heading = adress.heading;
      _name = adress.name;
      _address = adress.address;
      _telefon = adress.telefon;
      _email = adress.email;
      _isChecked = adress.isChecked;
    });
  }

  initialize() async {
    addressList = address_model.fromJson(addressjson).addressobject!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: could you include provider.initialize() too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your provider.initialize() with widgetsbinding

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => provider.initialize(),);
```

Comment: Though it prevents the error but now the state is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

you cant call 'setState' or `changeNotifier` before build. because the widget doesnt mounted yet.

maybe you can try this

```
 Future initializeEAProvider() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration());
    await locator<EAProvider>().initialize();
  }
```

its not good maybe ,but you can try it

Comment: your solution didn't work!

Comment: what is actually locator? cant find in your code